# How to restore LayoutManager of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

It will be a trivial question, but I fairly new in the world Android.
The scenario is this: I have a multiple choice for display some elements, **GridLayoutManager** and **LinearLayoutManager**, not knowing what to do, now I have a dirty code like this:

*snippet of code in onOptionItemSelected*;
Below, I have to create an Object of LinearLayoutManager and on of GridLayoutManager, and then set the layout of RecyclerView

```
case R.id.visualizza:{
            // isList() return true only if getLayoutManager() == LinearLayoutManager
            if(isList()){
                // setta il titolo del menu item con la stringa txtList
                item.setTitle(getString(R.string.txtList));
                mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
            }else{
                item.setTitle(getString(R.string.txtGrid));
                mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
            }
            break;
}
```

*Here in onRestoreInstanceState()*; Here too, I had to create an object both for Linear and for Grid... This I think is **not a good practice**!
But I do not know how to solve.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("seiList")){
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    }else{
        mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    }
}
```

What I want, is something that provides the setting of LinearLayout if is the first time that the app being used, while for the rest, simply keep the user's choice.

I hope I have passed well what my problem and that someone is happy to help!

**UPDATE**
I solved through [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences) doing a check in **onStop()**

```
if (isList()){
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("linear", true).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in order to to save preference data.

so let's say it's the first time the user uses your app:

```
public void onCreate(...){
    ....
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean isFirstUse = sp.getBoolean(PREF_IS_FIRST_TIME, true);

    if(isFirstUse){
        final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_IS_FIRST_TIME, false).apply();
    }
```

then you can decide easily which `LayoutManager` to use. of course that you
can also use the `SharedPreferences` in order to save user choices. this is what the `SharedPreferences` is all about.

also you should not use `onRestoreInstanceState` in order to initialize views.
you should only use it in order to extract data that you have saved inside the `Bundle` at [onSavedInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: well you will have to give much more detail than that answer (-;

Comment: I updated the Answer, I understand how to leverage SharedPreferences.
But how can I tell if it's the first time?